# Why is my div moving to right whenever I add "overflow-y: scroll"?

Tags: html, css

Why is my div moving to right whenever I specify `overflow-y: scroll` on the `.messages` element?

Even when I use `margin-left: -10px;`, it doesn't move to the left!

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,900);
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);
 [class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: #BDC1C6;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
p {
  font-weight: 300;
}
.chat {
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  background: #35323C;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.menu-icon {
  background: #2F2E33;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.menu-icon:hover {
  background: #39caad;
  cursor: pointer;
}
h1 {
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
.menulist {
  background: #39caad;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menulist:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
.openchat {
  background: #39caad;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
.new {
  background: rgb(57, 202, 173);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
.new:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(57, 202, 173, 0.9);
}
.messages {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;
}
.message {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.message p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.message:hover {
  background: #39caad;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.messageSender {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.messageSender p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.messageReceiver {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.messageReceiver p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 15px 0;
}
img.sender {
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: right !important;
  margin: 0 10px 15px 0;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
img.receiver {
  border-radius: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 15px 0;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
p.time {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 400;
}
p.chattime {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
h2:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #39caad;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
h2.send:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #39caad;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
h2.send:after {
  content: '';
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-radius: 00%;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
footer p:before,
footer p:after {
  content: ' - ';
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <header>
    <div class="menu-icon" id="menubutton"><span class="entypo-menu"></span>
    </div>

    <h1>Chats</h1>
  </header>
  <?php include( "menu.php"); ?>
  <div class="openchat" id="openchat">
    <img style="width:35px; height: 35px;" src="http://dtechnomist.com/clients/chat/assets/users/2.jpg" />
    <h2>XYZ</h2>
    <p class="time">Online</p>
  </div>
  <section class="messages" id="chatBox">
    <div class="messageReceiver">
      <img class="receiver" src="assets/users/1.jpg">
      <h2 class="receive">Admin 1</h2>
      <p class="chattime">12:00:00 AM, 3rd Jan16</p>
      <p>There ?</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="messageSender">
      <img class="sender" src="assets/users/2.jpg">
      <h2 class="send"> You</h2>
      <p class="chattime">12:00:00 AM, 4th Jan16</p>
      <p>Yes</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="messageReceiver">
      <img class="receiver" src="http://dtechnomist.com/clients/chat/assets/users/1.jpg">
      <h2 class="receive">Admin 1</h2>
      <p class="chattime">08:59:33 PM, 4th Jan16</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="messageReceiver">
      <img class="receiver" src="assets/users/1.jpg">
      <h2 class="receive">Admin 1</h2>
      <p class="chattime">09:05:55 PM, 4th Jan16</p>
      <p>hi</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="messageReceiver">
      <img class="receiver" src="http://dtechnomist.com/clients/chat/assets/users/1.jpg">
      <h2 class="receive">Admin 1</h2>
      <p class="chattime">09:06:02 PM, 4th Jan16</p>
      <p>ok</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="messageSender">
      <img class="sender" src="http://dtechnomist.com/clients/chat/assets/users/2.jpg">
      <h2 class="send"> You</h2>
      <p class="chattime">09:06:58 PM, 4th Jan16</p>
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="messageSender">
      <img class="sender" src="http://dtechnomist.com/clients/chat/assets/users/2.jpg">
      <h2 class="send"> You</h2>
      <p class="chattime">09:07:08 PM, 4th Jan16</p>
      <p>hi</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="messageSender">
      <img class="sender" src="http://dtechnomist.com/clients/chat/assets/users/2.jpg">
      <h2 class="send"> You</h2>
      <p class="chattime">09:07:31 PM, 4th Jan16</p>
      <p>asd</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="write">
    <textarea type="text" name="msg" id="msg" style="width:85%; height: 30px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 2%; resize: none" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
    <button name="send" id="sendMsg" style="width: 9%;"><span class="entypo-plus"></span>Send</button>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>Designed by <a href="kashanshah.tk">Kashan Shah</a>
    </p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide coding you used please / jsfiddle ??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ve9d4f36/

This is the code..
this tag is not going at the left most!
<section class="messages" id="chatBox">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior due to [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

When you add `overflow-y: scroll` to the element, a [new block formatting context is established](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), which means that the `.openchat` element's vertical margin no longer collapses with the `.messages` element. Since the margins no longer collapse, the element is shifted to the right.

> Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with `overflow` other than `visible`) do not collapse with their in-flow children.

To resolve this issue, you could either add `overflow: hidden` to the `.openchat` element in order hide the overflowing margin (which essentially prevents the margin from adjoining):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/0w6rpy4w/)

```
.openchat {
    background: #39caad;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could also just remove the `margin-bottom` from the child `img` element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mujda3z5/)

```
.openchat img {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```